# Is backing up the mdb and log files enough to restore TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm about to wipe my system drive which has my SQL Server mdb and log files. I've backed up these files. I'm using TFS.

After reinstalling Windows, SQL Server, and TFS, if I put back the mdb and log files for Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_DefaultCollection (these are the only TFS related SQL Server files I have) will that be enough to restore all my TFS history? To be clear, all I care about is the source control aspect. I only use TFS to check-in/check-out code.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to back up and restore an instance of TFS is to use the integrated backup tool, which ensures that the databases are properly synchronized and in a state that is restorable.

Answer (score 0):

No, this may cause some unknown problems when you try to restore data to TFS in the feature.

Recommend you to use the built-in tools of TFS and configure a Backup Plan. Just as Daniel said, it's the safest way. More details please refer this blog: [Backing up and Restoring your TFS Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2010/08/18/backing-up-and-restoring-your-tfs-server/)

[image]